# Chess Engine TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, chess, python-3.1

```
board = [["bRook", "bKnight", "bBishop", "bQueen", "bKing", "bBishop", "bKnight", "bRook"],
         ["bPawn", "bPawn",   "bPawn",   "bPawn",  "bPawn", "bPawn",   "bPawn",   "bPawn"],
         ["",      "",        "",        "",       "",      "",        "",        ""],
         ["",      "",        "",        "",       "",      "",        "",        ""],
         ["",      "",        "",        "",       "",      "",        "",        ""],
         ["",      "",        "",        "",       "",      "",        "",        ""],
         ["wPawn", "wPawn",   "wPawn",   "wPawn",  "wPawn", "wPawn",   "wPawn",   "wPawn"],
         ["wRook", "wKnight", "wBishop", "wQueen", "wKing", "wBishop", "wKnight", "wRook"]]


def evaluation():
#Material Score
materialScoreWhite = 0
materialScoreBlack = 0
#Main Material
pieceScores = {"Pawn": 100,
               "Knight": 320,
               "Bishop": 330,
               "Rook": 500,
               "Queen": 900,
               "King": 20000}

    for each in board:
        for f in each:
            if f[0] == "w":
                materialScoreWhite += "w" + pieceScores[each[0:]]
            elif f[0] == "b":
                materialScoreBlack += "b" + pieceScores[each[0:]]
```

I am trying to make a simple chess engine in Python. The list `board` shows how the board is in the position the program is trying to evaluate. Part of my evaluation involves going through each piece on the board and adding a certain value to the score that colour has.

For example, the first piece in the list at the moment (the starting position) is a black rook so I want the program to add `500` to `materialScoreBlack`. However, I keep getting this error:

```
    materialScoreBlack += "b" + pieceScores[each[0:]]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `each[0:]` is a *copy* of the list, which cannot be used as a dictionary key. Did you mean `each[0]` (the first element *in* the list)?

Comment: I now get this error: materialScoreBlack += "b" + pieceScores[each[0]]
KeyError: 'bRook'

Comment: Of course you do; look at `pieceScores`, is `'bRook'` a key in there?!

Comment: Addding a string ("b" or "w") to an integer (`materialScoreBlack`) is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access pieceScores with `each[0:]`, which is a "slice" of the array each, which is just a shorter list. You can't access a dictionary at a list! I think what you meant to do is something like

```
materialScoreBlack += pieceScores[f[1:]]
```

Which accesses the dictionary correctly. Also note that I changed your slice starting at 0 to a slice starting at 1. This is to remove the w/b at the beginning of the entries in your board, so that the dictionary can be accessed. I didn't make it

```
materialScoreBlack += "b" + pieceScores[f[1:]]
```

because I wasn't sure what you were trying to do with the "b" -- materialScoreBlack looks and sounds like it should be a number, so don't try to add strings to it <strike>even if Python lets you do it</strike>.

Comment: *"even if Python lets you do it"* - it won't, Python is dynamically **but strongly** typed.

Comment: I suppose I meant "even if the _compiler_ allows it," since it sounded as though the code was compiling, at least.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're trying to do with the line

```
materialScoreWhite += "w" + pieceScores[each[0:]]
```

adding "w" or "b" doesn't seem to make sense to me, and you can't access your dictionary like this. Just tried the code, starting at second element in f and it works fine

```
def evaluation():

materialScoreWhite = 0
materialScoreBlack = 0
#Main Material
pieceScores = {"Pawn": 100,
               "Knight": 320,
               "Bishop": 330,
               "Rook": 500,
               "Queen": 900,
               "King": 20000}

for each in board:
    for f in each:
        if len(f) > 0:
            if f[0] == "w":
                materialScoreWhite += pieceScores[f[1:]]
            elif f[0] == "b":
                materialScoreBlack += pieceScores[f[1:]]

print materialScoreBlack
print materialScoreWhite
```